# Dual screens and maximized video on Yosemite

Tags: macos, mac, screen

So when I maximize a video on Mac (Yosemite) it renders my other monitor useless.  It sucks when watching videos on Lynda.com and trying to work along with it. Is there a work around or an option to disable this "Feature"?

Answer (score 1):

In short, no.

OS X has always behaved like this.
The only alternative is to use maximised rather than fullscreen, though that is app-dependent, especially when it comes to video playback…

For instance, VLC can do it, Youtube can't.

If the window has the traffic light buttons, top left, it can. If it doesn't - like a Youtube video where the main window has those but the video itself doesn't, you're stuck.